# Amazon Prime like checkout process (ship prime sku fast, ship non prime sku slower)

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping

Is there a amazon prime like magento addon available?
We sell spare parts. A product attribute stores if the sku is prime yes or no.
In the checkout process magento should group prime sku and non prime sku and user selects shipping method for each group (express for prime, standard for non prime or standard for all). This should improve our lead time from order to delivery as the warehouse people can priorize prime sku in one order.